# Notifying when a FindFiles Process has finished

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have a multi threaded app where I have created a Producer/Consumer Pattern for the processing of XML files etc

What I want to know is what would be a good approach for updates to the UI and when the process finshed.

Should I go down a threaded approach and create Barrier and wait for all tasks to complete or should I just create an event/delegate and get the UI to catch this for both UI updates/compeltion

Comment: It can, indeed, be somewhat difficult to tell when operations like this are complete. I guess the condition for completion is that (the 'FindFiles' task has reached the end of its search) AND (the number of completed tasks=number of created tasks).  You could 'BeginInvoke' the completed, (or errored), tasks to the UI thread for handling of some sort of progress indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout [Signalr](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) which allows you to achieve PUSH notifications to clients.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, this answer was assuming Windows Forms, because there was no asp.net tag at first.  Hopefully someone will provide a good answer for asp.net as well.**

You can use Form.Invoke() to update stuff from the non-GUI thread, here's a simple example:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(DoStuff);
        thread.Start();
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Hey, this was invoked")));
    }
```

With Invoke, you can do just about anything with the Form, it runs the invoked action in the form's thread.  So you can change your status text or whatever that way.  Of course, you shouldn't have your "business logic" inside the Form class, and you shouldn't use Thread.Sleep, I'm just showing the very basic fact that you can call back to the UI thread this way.

---

As to whether you should wait for all tasks to complete before doing anything, or show status updates as they execute, that's really up to you.  I like to show updates on the UI when possible so the user knows what's going on.  It's also good to have a progress bar going if there's something happening that the user might be waiting for.  The progress bar can just be a marquee if you don't have a good way to indicate real progress.

Comment: Given the tags on the question are asp.net mvc, I don't think this answer really applies? :)

Comment: That tag wasn't there when I posted.  :(

Comment: You where too quick ...I submitted post and added aspnet 10 secs latter ...Want to update UI as well

Comment: I'm guessing you're thinking of having ajax communication between the page and the server?  So you make one ajax call that starts the multithreaded operation, and then continue making calls to check on the progress?